# Symfony2 problems with custom User provider

Tags: security, symfony

i got some problems with the custom User entity provider in Symfony2.

I've got this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class Cms\ControlPanel\UserBundle\Entity\User contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getUsername) in /Users/mathijs/workspaces/cms/src/Cms/ControlPanel/UserBundle/Entity/User.php line 144
```

User.php:144:

```
public function equals(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $user->getEmail() == $this->getEmail();
}
```

It says something about getUsername, but in my file stays: getEmail.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The errors means the class `User` is missing the method `getUsername`. Implement the method `getUsername` in class `User`.

```php
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->email;
}
```